# Commit ok, but sync reverted everything to previous state

Tags: git, synchronization, github-for-mac

I used github for mac this morning. did a commit locally of a massive number of changes, worked ok. Then tried to sync that's where something went wrong
My unsynced commit didn't show in the list anymore, but the online repository wasn't updated  and my local files have been reverted to the previous online repository's state

Did I just loose days of work with a simple click? Or can I actually restore what I did because the local commit worked! But it looks like it disappeared, it doesn't appear anywhere in the software

It's like all the work I put up never happened, vanished

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you've lost your work. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "sync" (push?, pull?, ..)? Git itself usually never discards any changes by itself, so wont any git client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you lost all your work. If you committed locally your work should remain in the git repo. Please refer to the [`git log`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) command.
Try something like

```
git log --full-history
```

or

```
git log --sparse
```

If you found the SHA1 ID you can try git cherry-pick to grab this commit and put it on top of your actual state.

Comment: thanks man, that put me on the right track
i had made changes using the github website to a readme file before pushing my changes online  
so when i asked for sync the software automatically created a different branch and switched to it
it wasn't *visually* obvious so i didn't understand and freaked out
i just switched to the right branch it's all working ok now
sorry for the newbie question, thanks for the command tips i'll remember them
cheers, ben